# How to change image from adapter when user press button?

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I have a adapter and the on click is inside this adapter like this :

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    final Movie currentMovie = movieList.get(position);

    holder.textView.setText(currentMovie.getMovieName());

    try {
        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.imageView, currentMovie.getMoviePictureLinkString(), R.drawable.placeholder_logo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder_logo));
    }


    try {
        if (currentMovie.getMoviePurchaseDetail() == Movie.PURCHASE_BOUGHT) {
            holder.tagImage.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tag_upgrade));

        } else if (currentMovie.getMoviePurchaseDetail() == Movie.PURCHASE_BUY) {
            holder.tagImage.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tag_buy));

        } else if (currentMovie.getMoviePurchaseDetail() == Movie.PURCHASE_DEFAULT) {
            holder.tagImage.setBackgroundResource(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (currentMovie.getMoviePurchaseDetail() == Movie.PURCHASE_DEFAULT) {

                LinkConfig
                        .loadMovieLink(context, currentMovie);

            } else if (currentMovie.getMoviePurchaseDetail() == Movie.PURCHASE_BOUGHT) {

                LinkConfig
                        .loadMovieLink(context, currentMovie);


                /*if (loginType == Util.LOGIN_TYPE_ACCOUNT) {
                    LinkConfig
                            .loadMovieLink(context, currentMovie);

                } else {
                    showDialogForFreeUser();

                }*/


            } else {

                MultipleUsedMethods.showBuyDialog(
                        context, currentMovie);

               /* if (loginType == Util.LOGIN_TYPE_ACCOUNT) {
                    MultipleUsedMethods.showBuyDialog(
                            context, currentMovie);
                } else {
                    showDialogForFreeUser();

                }*/


            }

        }
    });



}
```

now when i click on anyitem it goes through different methods and after one successfull condition in some method i have to change the tag in the adapter for this condition :

```
  try {
        if (currentMovie.getMoviePurchaseDetail() == Movie.PURCHASE_BOUGHT) {
            holder.tagImage.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tag_upgrade));

        } else if (currentMovie.getMoviePurchaseDetail() == Movie.PURCHASE_BUY) {
            holder.tagImage.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tag_buy));

        } else if (currentMovie.getMoviePurchaseDetail() == Movie.PURCHASE_DEFAULT) {
            holder.tagImage.setBackgroundResource(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

how can i change this tagImage for the adapter from another method? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a callback in your adapter, so you can bind to it from let say your activity like this (I translated this from my C# code so it might look a bit wierd but you get the idea):

```
// call this from activity
// Put your logic/conditions here. Then update the adapter with the given position
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(someCallback);
```

Callback interface

```
interface ICallback{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

In your adapter

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(ICallback callback){
  this.callback = callback
}

@Override
public void onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView =  // inflate your layout here
        var vh = new ImageViewHolder (itemView, this.callback);
        return vh;
    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

   final SomeClass item = yourList.get(position);

   holder.view.setText(item.getYourData());
   // Don't put any logic in this function
   // only set your data to view here
```

Your Holder class:

```
public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView image;

    public ImageViewHolder (View itemView, ICallback callback) : base (itemView)
    {
        v = (View)itemView.findViewById(Resource.Id.image);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(callback != null)
                callback.onItemClick(super.position)
        });
    }
}
```

You have the position of clicked item in the adapter, you could easily edit its values in the adapter. You should not put any logic in onBindViewHolder of the adapter. Instead, execute the logic in maybe your activity, then set new data to the adapter, and notify the changes.